# Javascript Confirm not Stopping request from post back if pressed cancel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, confirm, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using Javascript function with `confirm()` message box and also having `RequiredFieldValidator` if I press cancel on my confirm message box but ValidatorGroup is true then it not stopping a request from getting post back.

I want to implement in such a way that If validatorGroup is treu but function return false then request should not get post back

Here is my Code:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnStaffSendRequest" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClientClick="UploadRefrrel()"
                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="SaveRequestGroup" OnClick="btnStaffSendRequest_OnClick"
                        TabIndex="1000" />
```

Here is my Javascript Function:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                            function UploadRefrrel() {
                                var hiddenFile = this.document.getElementById("<%= hfInputForm.ClientID %>");
                                var upload = $find("<%= radUploadFiles.ClientID %>");
                                var inputs = upload.getUploadedFiles();
                                var retVal;
                                if (hiddenFile != null && hiddenFile.value != "" && inputs.length == 0) {
                                    retVal = confirm("FYI - Only 'Referral Form' is attached. Do you want to proceed without any other attachment?");
                                }
                                return retVal;
                            }
                        </script>
```

Comment: initially set `var retVal =false;`

Comment: No its not working I am having near about 20 controls in my `ValidateGroup` that is `SaveRequestGroup` and if I filled all them then ValidateGroup is true but on Button Click I checked condition and If select Cancel still the Request is getting post back is there any way if my ValidateGroup is true but Javascript function return false then stopping request to get post back

Comment: this soultion might not be definitive solution but it works because we came up with such situations : Sol : Create a hidden variable and try to call the javascript function in OnCLientClick and if your JS vaslidation is `true` , set that Hidden variable to `true` and check that status in code behind along with your validationfroup status ..

Comment: System.Web.HttpException is occurs when try to Validate HiddenField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validatePostBack" runat="server" Display="None" ClientValidationFunction="Validate_PostBack"
                        ValidationGroup="SaveRequestGroup" ErrorMessage="<br /> Please add other attachment."></asp:CustomValidator>                  
                    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="uploadReferel" runat="server">
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function Validate_PostBack(sender, e) {
                            var hiddenFile = this.document.getElementById("<%= hfInputForm.ClientID %>");
                            var upload = $find("<%= radUploadFiles.ClientID %>");
                            var inputs = upload.getUploadedFiles();

                            if (hiddenFile != null && hiddenFile.value != "" && inputs.length == 0) {
                                var retVal = confirm("FYI - Only 'Referral Form' is attached. Do you want to proceed without any other attachment?");
                                if (retVal == true) {
                                    e.IsValid = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    e.IsValid = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

Found my solution and working fine